# Updating state object inside an array from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

First I want to apologize because I'm newbie using react, so for sure I'm doing something really messed up.

That said, I need to update a specific state at parent component from child component, i'm using a handler inside the parent component to handle all the state changes, but it doesn't seem to work when I have arrays and objects, also I can add objects into 'inpHotel' state, so far what I got:

#### Parent

```
state = {
    activeStep: 0,
    fade: false,
    inpDestino: null,
    inpPeriodo: null,
    inpHotel: [{
        "nomeHotel": null,
        "urlMenorPreco": null,
        "quartos":[]
    }],
    inpNome: null,
    inpEmail: null,
    inpCelular: null,
};

//Handle function
handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
};
```

#### Child

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
    <TextField
        defaultValue={values.inpHotel[length].quartos[i].categoriaQuarto}
        onChange={     
            handleChange(`inpHotel[${length}].quartos[${i}].categoriaQuarto`)
        }
    />
</Grid>
```

### EDIT 1

My state needs to look like this JSON

```
{
    "chCidade": 0,
    "dataCheckIn": "",  
    "dataCheckOut": "",  
    "nome": "",
    "sobrenome": "",
    "celular": "",
    "email": "",
    "hoteis":
    [
        {   
            "nomeHotel": "",
            "urlMenorPreco": "",
            "quartos":[{
                "categoriaQuarto": "",
                "menorPrecoDiaria": 0,
                "quantidadeAdulto": "",
                "criancas":[{"idade":0},{"idade":0}]
            },{
                "categoriaQuarto": "",
                "menorPrecoDiaria": 0,
                "quantidadeAdulto": 0,
                "criancas":[]
            }]
        },
        {
            "nomeHotel": "",
            "urlMenorPreco": "",
            "quartos":[{
                "categoriaQuarto": "",
                "menorPrecoDiaria": 0,
                "quantidadeAdulto": 0,
                "criancas":[{"idade":0},{"idade":0}]
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try this: `onChange={     
            () => handleChange(`inpHotel[${length}].quartos[${i}].categoriaQuarto`)
        }`

Comment: On child component try to do: onChange={ () => handleChange(paramYouWantToSend) }

Comment: I think you could use [React State Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Comment: @noobprogrammer didn't work as expected, but thanks for your time!

Comment: @T04435 i'm reading and trying to understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you are using `e.target.value` which is the event, but you are not passing the event object on your `onChange`.

Try this

`onChange={(e) => handleChange(inpHotel[${length}].quartos[${i}].categoriaQuarto, e)}`

Here's a sample code: https://codepen.io/gadawag/pen/vPoavP?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `handleChange()` directly and it will return `undefined`. So you are setting `onChange` event to `undefined`.You could use wrapper function

```
onChange={() => handleChange(`inpHotel[${length}].quartos[${i}].categoriaQuarto`)}
```

Comment: Almost! With that he created a new state:
inpHotel[0].quartos[0].categoriaQuarto: "ewqeqweq"